# how to restrict certain data in $random in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I want to randomize a variable in verilog. So I am using $random for that.But $random may generate 0 which I don't want 0 avlue for my the variable.
how to restrict the value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$dist_uniform ( seed , start , end )` in Verilog, or its replacement  `$urandom_range(max [,min])` in SystemVerilog.